# Would adding a dynamic tooltip affect load time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, erb, load-time

I have a table "State", consisting of a few thousand records, and I'm printing each of their names on one page. Would adding a dynamic tooltip to each add noticeably to the load time of the page? In other words, would there be a significant performance difference between these two blocks of code?

```
<%= State.all.each do |state| %>
  <%= state.name %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= State.all.each do |state| %>
  <%= link_to state.name, "#", title: "(" + state.weather + ")" %>
<% end %>
```

---

For the record, `weather` is a instance method calculated by adding two State attributes together:

```
def weather
  self.snow + self.rain
end
```

Comment: You might consider paginating your results and making them searchable instead of having to put everything in a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know you can easily check the log, it shows you the active record time and the view rendering time

It would look something like this

```
Completed 200 OK in 539ms (Views: 486.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

The first `200` means that the request was a success, the 2nd number `539ms` is the total request time, which in this case is '539 milliseconds', then there's a break down of that time, `486.9ms` was spent in the view rendering, and `1.8ms` is spent in the `ActiveRecord` queries

Test both cases, I don't think you'll find any huge difference but you should check

PS: you should move the query call to the controller, just for good convention

```
# controller
@states = State.all

#view
<%= @states.each do |state| %>
```

Comment: What do the various numbers mean in the log?

Comment: well the first 200 means that the request was a success, the 2nd number `539ms` is the total request time, which in this case is 539 milliseconds, then there's a break down of that time, `486.9ms` was spent in the view rendering, and `1.8ms` is spent in the activerecord queries, it's well known that the most expensive operation in rails is the view rendering, that's why caching views improves the performance a lot